# How to use JUnit 5 console launcher flags in Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5

By looking at the documentation in [here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher) I see there's an option that allows using different class name endings `-n, --include-classname <String>`.

I would like to know if it is possible to specify such flag (and others) inside my build.gradle script so that when I run `gradlew build` are used at the moment of running the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow your link and read section http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-filters -- below the section "4.2.1. Gradle":

```
junitPlatform {
    filters {
        includeClassNamePattern '.*Spec'
        includeClassNamePatterns '.*Test', '.*Tests'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct to delete my question in this situation since isn't very insightful and could be simply solved?